# Animal class in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, class, object

I want to make an Animal class in c++ using string. But it look like by using string it show so much of error and doesn't get resolve. Can someone help me what is wrong in my code?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Animal {
char str1[100], str2[100], str3[100];
public :
void setData(char a, char b, char c); 
void getData() {
    cout<<"The type of animal is "<<str1[100]<<endl;
    cout<<"The name of "<<str1[100]<<" is "<<str2[100]<<endl;
    cout<<" "<<str1[100]<<" "<<str3[100]<<endl;

}

void Animal :: setData(char a, char b, char c) {
  str1[100] = a;
  str2[100] = b;
  str3[100] = c;
 }

 int main() {

  Animal isha;
  isha.setData('D', 'T', 'B');
  isha.getData();

  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: You have syntax errors. Add `};` at the end of your class definition.

Comment: You have **undefined behavior** (due `str1[100] = a;
  str2[100] = b;
  str3[100] = c;`) to  in your program in addition to syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

You have **undefined behavior** in your program because you're going out of bounds of the array `str1`, `str2` and `str3` in addition to syntax errors as explained below:

##### Problem 1

You're missing the closing brace `}` and a semicolon `;` for the class. To solve this add `};` at the end of the class definition as shown below.

##### Problem 2

Even after fixing the syntax error, you will have **undefined behavior** in your program because you're going out of bounds of the arrays `str1`, `str2` and `str3` when you wrote:

```
void getData() {
//----------------------------------vvvvvvvvv---------------->undefined behavior
    cout<<"The type of animal is "<<str1[100]<<endl;
//------------------------vvvvvvvvv----------vvvvvvvvv------->undefined behavior
    cout<<"The name of "<<str1[100]<<" is "<<str2[100]<<endl;
//-------------vvvvvvvvv-------vvvvvvvvv--------------------->undefined behavior
    cout<<" "<<str1[100]<<" "<<str3[100]<<endl;

}
void Animal :: setData(char a, char b, char c) {
  str1[100] = a; //undefined behavior
  str2[100] = b;//undefined behavior
  str3[100] = c;//undefined behavior
 }
```

##### Solution

Better would be to use `std::string` instead of built in arrays and make sure that you're don't go out of bounds of the array(in case arrays are used) as shown below. The code given is a demonstration of how to fix the issues.

```
class Animal {
    std::string str1, str2, str3;
    public :
        void setData(std::string a, std::string b, std::string c); 
        void getData() {
            std::cout<<"The type of animal is "<<str1<<std::endl;
            std::cout<<"The name of "<<str1<<" is "<<str2<<std::endl;
            std::cout<<" "<<str1<<" "<<str3<<std::endl;
        
        }
};

void Animal :: setData(std::string a, std::string b, std::string c) {
  str1= a;
  str2= b;
  str3= c;
 }

 int main() {

  Animal isha;
  isha.setData("D", "T", "B");
  isha.getData();

  return 0;
 }
```

One of the reasons why using `std::string` is better here in your example is that using `char` arrays is that while using `char` arrays in your original example, you were wasting space as each of those array were of length `100`. By using `std::string` that wastage of space in longer there. Additionally, elements can be added and removed from a `std::string` and so this make the program more flexible.

Comment: Now the only thing that's missing fropm the answer is a short explanation of `char` vs. `std::string` and why `char` it was a poor choice in the first place, and why `str1[100] = xxx` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I added one or two advantage of using `std::string` over `char` arrays at the end of my answer. More than that i don't think is necessary here.

Comment: You missed the main part. Passing chars in order to store them in strings is pointless. Either pass string and store strings, or pass chars and store chars, but don't pass chars to store them in strings.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I've already made the parameters of `setData` to `std::string` instead of `char`.